# MySQL Python problem with two Placeholders

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a problem with my function:

```
def dataf (p,k):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',
                                             database='products',
                                             user='user',
                                             password='pwd')
        sql_select_Query = "select a from table where b LIKE %s AND c LIKE %s"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_select_Query, ('%' + p+ '%',), ('%' + k + '%',))
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        return records
    except Error as e:
        print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            connection.close()
            cursor.close()
```

When I execute this function with only the first placeholder, everything works fine. With the second placeholder I get the TypeError: NoneType

With the second placeholder I want to check if in column c a value is like = 0,5 kg for example. When I write the query without the second placeholder and insert the value directly, everything works fine:

```
sql_select_Query = "select a from table where b LIKE %s AND c LIKE '0,5 kg'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it with:

```
sql_select_Query = "select a from table where b LIKE %s AND c LIKE %s"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_select_Query, ('%' + p+ '%','%' + k + '%',))
```

I got the result.